# Counting each values by groups with NAs

Tags: r

I'm using this code for counting rows by fours. But it doesn't work when my df includes NA. How can I overcome this?

```
count <- sapply(split.default(df, 0:(length(df)-1) %/% 4), rowSums)
```

Normally **rowSums** has **na.rm=TRUE** but when I tried it here I'm getting this:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I tried different versions of lapply, sapply or apply but no one worked. I'm just a starter so it will be very simple but I couldn't success.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Small example:

```
id <- 1:12
b <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
df <-data.frame(b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b)
df$yeni <- sapply(split.default(df, 0:(length(df)-1) %/% 4), rowSums)
#   b b.1 b.2 b.3 b.4 b.5 b.6 b.7 b.8 b.9 b.10 yeni.0 yeni.1 yeni.2
#1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#3  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1      4      4      3
#4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#5  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#6  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1      4      4      3
#7  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1      4      4      3
#8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#9  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#10 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      0      0      0
#11 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1      4      4      3
#12 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1      4      4      3
```

My code doesn't work when my dataset is like this one

```
d <- c(0,NA,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
df <-data.frame(b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,d,d)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `df` an array and then use `rowSums`:

```
b <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
d <- c(0,NA,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
df <-data.frame(b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,d,d)
#convert to matrix
a <- as.matrix(df)
#fill with NA values and convert to array
i <- nrow(a)
j <- ceiling(ncol(a) / 4)
length(a) <- i * j * 4
dim(a) <- c(i, j, 4)
#rearrange dimensions of array
a <- aperm(a, c(1,3,2))
#calculate the sums
rowSums(a, na.rm = TRUE, dims = 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    4    4    4    1
# [4,]    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    4    4    4    1
# [7,]    4    4    4    1
# [8,]    0    0    0    0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0
#[11,]    4    4    4    1
#[12,]    4    4    4    1
```

Comment: Problem is my dataset isn't completely the same in my example. For example there are 12 column here but in real dataset there are 42,46 or 44. It can changes. When I apply this to my dataset it produce only first 12 columns result.

Comment: @ismailb No, this code gets the number of columns dynamically (using `ncol`).